# HTML Canvas, blurring drawn polygon

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made this (run snippet below)

```js
 var Canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = Canvas.getContext('2d');

    var resize = function() {
        Canvas.width = Canvas.clientWidth;
        Canvas.height = Canvas.clientHeight;
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    resize();

    var elements = [];
    var presets = {};

    presets.shard = function (x, y, s, random, color) {
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            draw: function(ctx, t) {
                this.x += 0;
                this.y += 0;
                var posX = this.x + + Math.sin((50 + x + (t / 10)) / 100) * 5;
                var posy = this.y + + Math.sin((55 + x + (t / 10)) / 100) * 7;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.moveTo(posX, posy);
                ctx.lineTo(posX+random,posy+random);
                ctx.lineTo(posX+random,posy+random);
                ctx.lineTo(posX+0,posy+50);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    };

    for(var x = 0; x < Canvas.width; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < Canvas.height; y++) {
            if(Math.round(Math.random() * 60000) == 1) {
                var s = ((Math.random() * 5) + 1) / 10;
                if(Math.round(Math.random()) == 1){
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 10;
                    var colorRanges = ['#8c8886', '#9c9995'];
                    var color = colorRanges[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorRanges.length)];
                    elements.push(presets.shard(x, y, s, random, color));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        for (var e in elements)
            elements[e].draw(ctx, time);
    }, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"\>
```

I just need to add one feature to be able to use it on the site I'm building it for. Some of the floating shards need to be blurred to give a sense of depth.

Can Canvas do this, and if so, how?

Comment: _Can Canvas do this, and if so, how?_ Try [explore it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) yourself

Comment: @markE I didn't say it's invalid, I just suggest the OP to try find solution yourself first.

Comment: @markE In order to convince the OP that Canvas has no ready-to-use function/method

Comment: @markE I don't see any foul here. It's a comment, not answer. And anyway it's worth reading the canvas docs for OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.filter = 'blur(10px)';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

Answer (score 1):

I used this few months ago, maybe it could work for you as well :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("heroCanvas");
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasBackground = new Image();
canvasBackground.src = "image.jpg";

var drawBlur = function() {
    // Store the width and height of the canvas for below
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    // This draws the image we just loaded to our canvas
    canvasContext.drawImage(canvasBackground, 0, 0, w, h);
    // This blurs the contents of the entire canvas
    stackBlurCanvasRGBA("heroCanvas", 0, 0, w, h, 100);
}

canvasBackground.onload = function() {
    drawBlur();
}
```

Here the source : http://zurb.com/playground/image-blur-texture

Comment: I saw that but I don't think that works with my drawn polygons. IT also blurs everthing I believe and I want to blur just some of them

Comment: I get it but I did the same thing as you with dots moving on the screen.
I used this function on specific dots so you can adapt it to specific polygons. Add  a variable in drawBlur function to pass specific values of image instead of "heroCanvas". I also added variables to blur the dots progressively.
I've modified a lot this function to make it suit.

Instead of image, you can called the function which create polygons.

Comment: @Majestic, I think you're on the right track, but your demo shows an empty screen in Chrome, FF & IE on Win10.

Comment: Could you perhaps share your modified version of the function. I'm still very new to the whole canvas thing so I'm very confused

Comment: @markE It does not work without adding an image. And you have to build the whole page with all basic needs.

Comment: @jansmolders86 I really would like to share it buddy but I did this in my previous job so I did not have the code =/
I'm pretty sure you can make it work if you try and re-try by modifying the function ^_^

Comment: @Majestic haha, never hurts to ask right? I'll try my best :) So this (after modding the code) also works if there is no image to blur?  Thanks!

Comment: @Majestic, Ok...so *"some-assembly-required"*. You might want to show your code without the snippet so people don't think you're providing running code. ;-)

Comment: @jansmolders86 Haha you're right :) I used images for dots but I think it also could if you draw the polygons with a function. Perhaps you'll have to adapt you draw function. If you can not do it, try to use polygons image. It could be a way to do it... Courage ;)

Comment: @markE This is what I wanted to do but as a newbie on stackoverflow, when I used the tag code it was disgusting. That's why I did this :/

Comment: @Majestic. No problem! Instead of using the code tag, just indent your code by 4 spaces and it will display well on Stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: Worth noting that it also needs an [external library](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html)